# How to solve this Grammar through SLR?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, left-recursion

I want to solve this Grammar.
    S->SS+
    S->SS*
    S->a

I want to construct SLR sets of items and parsing table with action and goto.
Can this grammar parse without eliminate left recursion.
Is this Grammar SLR.

Comment: No, you need to eliminate the left recursion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, this grammar is not SLR. It is ambiguous.
2. Left recursion is not a problem for LR parsers. Left recursion elimination is only necessary for LL parsers.

Comment: How can say that this grammar is SLR? Is there any way to find out?

Comment: @himanshusaini: construct the slr tables and observe that there are no conflicts.

Comment: yes,there is conflict in parsing table. So this is no SLR Grammar? Is there any way to find the grammar is SLR or not without making parsing tree.

Comment: @HimanshuSaini: Effectively, all algorithms to figure out whether a grammar is SLR are equivalent to "construct the SLR tables".

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure about this, but I think this grammar is actually SLR(1). I constructed by hand the SLR(1) table and I obtained one with no conflicts (having added a 0-transition from S' (new start symbol) -> S).

Can somebody provide a sentence that can be derived in two different ways from this grammar? I was able to get a parser for it in Bison without any warning. Are you sure it is ambiguous?